# Cannot adjust brightness in Xubuntu

Tags: lenovo, brightness, gpu

I has been a week I've been trying different fixes from **askubuntu.com** and other sites but no one seems to work.
I'm using Lenovo V14 notebook. I has an integrated GPU and a **Ryzen 5 4500U** . The brightness menu bar can be moved, and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work too, but it does nothing. I've tried the brightness controller fix, **xconf**, reinstalling the drivers, upgrading to **Xubuntu 20** and updating the kernel.
The sound and Wi-Fi controllers work ok.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing brightness controller
first type `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal then type `sudo apt install brightness-controller` then launch by typing `brightness-controller` it might help.

Comment: Hi. I've tryed that too. The brightness-controller changes the value of acpi_video0/brightness but the screen stays bright.

Answer (score 0):

On xubuntu 2022, installed brightnessctl [and dependencies] and then could find current brightness with "brightnessctl g" and adjust it with "sudo brightnessctl s 2000". g command gives max value allowed too and percentage of current level.

See man page...